# Is it possible to display up and coming Calendar entries on a homepage?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to encourage a team unfamiliar with SharePoint to use SharePoint to share knowledge and collaborate as well as using a shared calender as they would their own in Outlook. To try to make site homepage as informative a possible to users, is it possible to display forthcoming team calendar events (the next 5, for example) in a section on the homepage?
Any guidance in laymans temrs please - as I'm new to SharePoint.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with no code solution

1. Edit the Page
2. And select Insert Web Part
3. Now choose the calendar in question
4. Create a new view and set following
5. Item limit = 5
6. Filter condition is Start Date > [Today]

Comment: Thanks for you swift response Amal - much appreciated. When following your guidance, I'm inserting the whole calendar (month view). Can I reduce the size of the calendar on the homepage and to show the next 5 events?

Comment: @AndrewHood yes, edit the webpart property and you can see the view it is using. You should change the view as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Many thanks Amal - cracked it! Really appreciate your help witht this.

Comment: @AndrewHood cheers mate!